# "My trace file shows me "CPU_TIME" longer than "ELAPSED_TIME"

Tags: oracle11g

I'm doing TEST my own SQL on 11g RAC with CENTOS.

I ran a sql with this script.

```
alter session set timed_statistics = true;
alter session set STATISTICS_LEVEL = all;
alter session set EVENTS '10046 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 12';
alter session set sql_trace=true;
```

and got trace file like below...

```
********************************************************************************

select ISSU_ID
      ,BUYR_CORP_NO
      ,SELR_CORP_NO
      ,BROK_CORP_NO
      ,ISSU_DATE
      ,ISSU_TIME
      ,REGS_DATE
      ,INSERT_DATE
      ,INSERT_TIME
      ,SERV_ID
      ,TAX_TYPE
      ,POPS_CODE
      ,MODY_CODE
      ,IMPT_NO
      ,ACEP_STAT_DATE
      ,ACEP_END_DATE
      ,ISSU_SND_CODE
      ,STAT_CODE
      ,ISSU_SND_VAL
      ,ITEM_QUANT
      ,CHRG_AMT
      ,TAX_AMT
      ,TOTL_AMT
      ,BILL_SEQ_NO
      ,USER_ID
      ,SEND_MSG
      ,RECB_MSG
      ,ACCP_YN
      ,RECP_CODE
      ,MULT_ISSU_ID
      ,REQ_CHNEL
      ,REPT_USER_ID
      ,BFO_ISSU_ID
      ,MAIL_ACP_CODE
      ,ERR_CODE
      ,ERR_MSG
      ,URL_ID
      ,MGR_ID1
      ,MGR_ID2
      ,MGR_ID3
      ,NOTE1
      ,NOTE2
      ,NOTE3
      ,DOC_TYPE
      ,CERT_NTS
      ,BILL_TYPE
 from EGDB_ENC_MSTR
where rownum<10000000

call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch   666668     93.85      78.70     424374    1494818          0     9999999
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total   666670     93.85      78.70     424374    1494818          0     9999999

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 112  (RTAXBILL)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
   9999999    9999999    9999999  COUNT STOPKEY (cr=1494818 pr=424374 pw=0 time=22043507 us)
   9999999    9999999    9999999   TABLE ACCESS FULL EGDB_ENC_MSTR (cr=1494818 pr=424374 pw=0 time=18632205 us cost=122336 size=3529999647 card=9999999)


Rows     Execution Plan
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  SELECT STATEMENT   MODE: ALL_ROWS
9999999   COUNT (STOPKEY)
9999999    TABLE ACCESS   MODE: ANALYZED (FULL) OF 'EGDB_ENC_MSTR' (TABLE)



Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  SQL*Net message to client                  666668        0.00          1.58
  enq: KO - fast object checkpoint                3        0.00          0.00
  reliable message                                1        0.00          0.00
  direct path read                                2        0.01          0.01
  SQL*Net message from client                666668        0.01       2399.08
  SQL*Net more data to client                     2        0.00          0.00
********************************************************************************
```

I have 3 questions.

1. Why `CPU_TIME` is longer than `ELAPSED_TIME`?
   I read a doc telling me that `ELAPSED_TIME` includes wait event time. If it's true, Why `CPU_TIME` is longer than `ELAPSED_TIME`?
2. When I run a query on the client, It returns result sets in few milliseconds though, my trace file says `ELAPSED_TIME` is 78.70 SEC. Is this relevant to `FETCH CALL`? If it's true, `ELAPSED_TIME` in trace file is the amount time for fetching all result-set not for `ArraySize`. Is this right?
3. In wait event section, It says total wait time of `SQL*Net message from client` is 2399 SEC though, ELAPSED_TIME is much shorter than that. Why is this?

I'm so curious about the stats in trc file but I'm new to oracle database actually. Any advice would be very appreciated.